# Table of Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-series

I found that there are very good references on Fourier integral transform but none on Fourier series. Do you happen to know one?

Answer (score 0):

I usually check Folland's "Fourier Analysis and Its Applications". It's not comprehensive, but many common examples are included. The tables are on p.26-28